# Difference between 'play you' and 'play with you'

Tags: differences, prepositions

What is the difference between "I'll play you next" and "I'll play with you next". Is there a grammatical error in both, it both means the same...

Answer (score 8):

I feel that *"I'll play you"* is competitive, where as *"I'll play with you"* could be collaborative. So you could play someone at tennis, but you could play with someone in a doubles game.

Answer (score 3):

*I'll play you next* means that you will be my next opponent. *I'll play with you next* might also mean that, but generally it would suggest some less serious kind of ludic activity.

Answer (score 1):

In modern English, they are two different verbs (or two different meanings of a verb, if you will).

The OED says

> **13**. *trans*.
>
> **a**. To take part or engage in (a game, sport, etc.); to participate in (a sporting match or contest).

Intransitive "play" has a range of meanings, including one very similar to 13a., but many other specific senses, only some of them competitive.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if it's just me, but while a child saying *I'll play with you* might sound innocent, an adult saying it sounds rather sexual.

Comment: I think in the proper context the sexual connotation can be, and is, quickly discarded. Like, if you're on a tennis court, and people are waiting around to play, and you're discussing who plays with whom next.